# Extra characters are added to a video file downloaded via a Spring @RestController

Tags: spring, spring-boot, rest, video

I am downloading a file via a Spring @RestController returning the bytes of the video in the OutputStream of the ResponseEntity object.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/video/{id}/data")
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<OutputStream> getVideoData(@PathVariable("id") Long id, HttpServletResponse response) {
        try {
            for (Video video : videos) {
                if (id == video.getId()) {
                    if (videoDataMgr == null) {
                        videoDataMgr = VideoFileManager.get();
                    }
                    videoDataMgr.copyVideoData(video, response.getOutputStream());
                    return new ResponseEntity<OutputStream>(response.getOutputStream(), HttpStatus.OK);
                }
            }
            response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            logger.log (Level.WARNING, ioe.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

If I play the video being served and the downloaded video they both show the same content. However, the following test fails when comparing byte by byte the contents of the 2 MP4 files:

```
@Test
    public void testAddVideoData() throws Exception {
        Video received = videoSvc.addVideo(video);
        VideoStatus status = videoSvc.setVideoData(received.getId(),
                new TypedFile(received.getContentType(), testVideoData));
        assertEquals(VideoState.READY, status.getState());
        
        Response response = videoSvc.getData(received.getId());
        assertEquals(200, response.getStatus());
        
        InputStream videoData = response.getBody().in();
        byte[] originalFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(testVideoData));
        byte[] retrievedFile = IOUtils.toByteArray(videoData);
        assertTrue(Arrays.equals(originalFile, retrievedFile));
    }
```

Doing a comparison between the files I can see that the videos are almost the same except for some characters at the end(the content of the downloaded file is on the right):

[image: Comparison between files]

Where is {"ready": false} coming from?

Comment: Return `ResponseEntity.ok()`. Looks like you are writing the video twice. At least I assume `ivdeoDataMgr.copyVideoData` writes to the outputstream already.

Comment: Thanks @M.Deinum. What would be the body in the call to ResponseEntity.ok()?

Comment: Nothing, just an empty body.

Comment: ```return new ResponseEntity<OutputStream>(HttpStatus.OK);``` did the trick. Thanks again @M.Deinum.